# How to clear jmeter.log file during long run execution?

Tags: logging, process, jmeter

I have **JMeter** `3.0` node which has make load testing for 24 hours.
However, after 3 hours disk usage is overwhelmed by `jmeter.log`.

I tried to clean it on my own during a test execution but without any success.
I have tried:

```
truncate jmeter.log --size 0
cat /dev/null > jmeter.log
```

It always fails:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tester tester 27591745 Sep 14 06:55 jmeter.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tester tester        0 Sep 14 06:55 load_execution.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 tester tester    48320 Sep 14 06:41 minion_load.jmx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tester tester        0 Sep 14 06:42 report_res_20170914-064202.xml
[root@ec2-54-172-27-231.compute-1.amazonaws.com dev-us1]# ll
total 1064
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tester tester 28311748 Sep 14 06:55 jmeter.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tester tester      219 Sep 14 06:55 load_execution.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 tester tester    48320 Sep 14 06:41 minion_load.jmx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tester tester        0 Sep 14 06:42 report_res_20170914-064202.xml
[root@ec2-54-172-27-231.compute-1.amazonaws.com dev-us1]# ll
total 104
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tester tester 29422392 Sep 14 06:56 jmeter.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tester tester        0 Sep 14 06:56 load_execution.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 tester tester    48320 Sep 14 06:41 minion_load.jmx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tester tester        0 Sep 14 06:42 report_res_20170914-064202.xml
[root@ec2-54-172-27-231.compute-1.amazonaws.com dev-us1]# ll
```

Another file is cleared periodically. I used `crontab` for it.

I am starting JMeter in not GUI mode.

How to clear default `jmeter.log` or set any threshold when file reach .. size?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1. Add [OS Process Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) somewhere to your Test Plan
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Command: `/bin/bash`
   - Parameter 1: `-c`
   - Parameter 2: `> jmeter.log`

Something like

[image: JMeter clear log]

See [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) article for more information on invoking 3rd-party apps from JMeter tests.

Comment: thank you for the links. However, can you shortly explain what should your approach do? Does it clear file regularly, or it even isn't created? It isn't clear enough.

Comment: It will clear the file each time the sampler is called

Comment: why does this command converts file to binary file? And it is also growing during the run.

Comment: @nazar_art I explained why in my answer: because direct truncate on file causes NUL chars to be written where data was (and NUL is considered binary character), which is why you are not supposed to directly truncate log file.

Comment: @DmitriT I can't understand why this answer has some downvotes. It works excellent. It is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

If you are not particularly interested in contents of jmeter.log on INFO level, instead of truncating the log, you can reduce log level to WARN or ERR in `jmeter.properties`. Change:

```
log_level.jmeter=INFO
```

to

```
log_level.jmeter=WARN
```

If you want to keep logging to INFO or DEBUG level, consider using [Excalibur](https://excalibur.apache.org/logger.html) logger, which supports log rotation and can also be configured via `jmeter.properties`:

> ```
> # Excalibur logging provides the facility to configure logging using
> # configuration files written in XML. This allows for such features as
> # log file rotation which are not supported directly by JMeter.
> #
> # If such a file specified, it will be applied to the current logging
> # hierarchy when that has been created.
> # 
> #log_config=logkit.xml
> ```

Direct log truncation is generally not a recommended way to control log size for log4j and especially log4j2, as it may cause various issues (e.g. JMeter to stop writing log completely, or on next write, JMeter may restore large size again, except the beginning of the file will consist of NULL characters).

Comment: Good answer up to 3.1

Comment: @KirilS The reason why I couldn't select this answer is that I can't access JMeter properties. I have to use solution from UI only.

Answer (score 2):

If using JMeter 3.1 or lower, see Kyril S answer.

Note I advise you highly to uograde.
Since JMeter 3.2, log4j2 is used as logging implementation .

So configure it to fit your needs by opening jmeter/bin/log4j2.xml and set:

- log level to warn, default is INFO
- if you still have log, read them and check you don't have an issue as this file is usually empty when no issues are faced
- configure log rotation using log4j2 RollingFileappder:
- https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html